# ¿Cual es la mejor forma para guardar datos en Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

He estado trabajando en un proyecto donde genero un terreno procedural dividido por `meshes`, ahora mi idea es guardar estos `meshes` en una carpeta para luego cargar solo los que necesito.

He visto que puedo hacerlo con `FileStream` pero no se si esta sería la mejor forma.

Answer (score 3):

¿No analizaste usar `AssetDatabase.SaveAssets()`?

[[Editor scripting] How to save a script generated mesh as an asset/FBX?](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/39311/editor-scripting-how-to-save-a-script-generated-me.html)

Con esto persistes en la ruta que indiques en `CreateAsset()`

---

Puede consultar aqui:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.CreateAsset.html